# the css property command for multiple columns only works for me in Opera and IE, not in firefox, chrome, or safari

Tags: html, css

The html code below displays as two columns in Opera and IE10, but only one column in Chrome, Safari, and firefox.  Does anyone know why?
The styling code [ body{column-count: 2} ] only seems to work in Opera and IE10.

[

041613-1-html-columns

body{column-count: 2}

This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English. 
This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English.

This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English. 
This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English.

This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English. 
This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English.

This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English. 
This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English.

This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English. 
This is an html document written in English. This is an html document written in English.

]

Answer (score 3):

You need vendor prefixes. (e.g., `-webkit-column-count: 2` and `-moz-column-count: 2`) See http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.